# @CrossOrigin annotation stops compilation in IntelliJ

Tags: java, spring, maven, intellij-idea, spring-boot

When I compile any class that contains the Spring `@org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.CrossOrigin` annotation using maven from the command line, it compiles just fine. But, when I try to compile the same code using IntelliJ Idea 15, I get this weird error:

```
[ERROR] /Users/gregederer/devewx2/geoengine/src/main/java/geoengine/controller/rest/TimeSeriesController.java:[34,1] annotation org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.CrossOrigin is missing value for the attribute <clinit>
```

This could be related to https://community.oracle.com/message/4827054. But, that issue was never really resolved.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can exclude the error from being included in the validation through IntelliJ by right clicking it and then it should compile.

Edit: It appears updating the JDK is the appropriate fix, my suggestion was intended to quickly bypass the issue and was more of a bandaid fix as the validation error should not have affected anything. See Nikki's answer for her explanation.

Comment: This shouldn't be the accepted answer. See Nikki's answer. http://stackoverflow.com/a/35544977/423045

Answer (score 13):

Try using JDK 1.7.0_80. I encountered this issue using JDK 1.7.0_79. Worked on 1.7.0_80 though.

Answer (score 1):

I'm having the same problem... Excluding it from validation did not help in my case. When I compile it from cmd with mvn, everything works fine, but from intellij, it does not. 
My intellij settings forced the use of java jdk 1.7 (needed for the project). When I set it to 1.8, I have no problems. I suppose this is a bug in javac 7 (see [here](http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/compiler-dev/2014-October/009065.html)).

> I've encountered the (known and resolved in 1.8) problem with javac
>   failing on annotations with static final fields requiring complex
>   initialization. The failure manifests itself on the latest 1.7

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue while deploying my app in travis ci which had installed oracle jdk 1.7.0_76. I force-updated jdk7, then upgraded to jdk 1.7.0_80. The @CrossOrigin annotation did not complain after that.

Answer (score 0):

After facing this issue today I also browsed through the Internet and couldn't find a straight answer. In my case using a higher Java version was not possible, because project was to be deployed to JDK 6. However in the end I found the solution, hope it will help someone else.

Key point is **Java is backwards compatible**.

That's the answer :) . You can use a higher `JDK` version like `1.7 or 1.8` to compile your project and use `-target` option to cross compile to lower version.

> -target version
>
> Generate class files that target a specified version of the VM. Class files will run on the specified target and on later versions, but not on earlier versions of the VM. Valid targets are 1.1, 1.2, 1.3, 1.4, 1.5 (also 5), 1.6 (also 6), and 1.7 (also 7).
>
> The default for -target depends on the value of -source:
>
> If -source is not specified, the value of -target is 1.7
>
> If -source is 1.2, the value of -target is 1.4
>
> If -source is 1.3, the value of -target is 1.4
>
> If -source is 1.5, the value of -target is 1.7
>
> If -source is 1.6, the value of -target is 1.7
>
> For all other values of -source, the value of -target is the value of -source.

Ref: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javac.html

I was using Maven so I just had to change `<java.version>` property in the `POM` and that was it. I was still using Java 8, with the latest Maven however maven was cross compiling to JDK6.